# Trying to write a recursive function to get just the unique numbers in list

Tags: python

I'm trying to do it where the list is split in two and the function picks the unique numbers from the first half and then calls itself again with the second half of the list. I'm just a little stuck at this point, as this only gives me the first half numbers.

```
def function(Lst):
    s = set()
   

    mid = len(Lst)//2
    for item in Lst[:mid]:
```

Thank you for the direction.
Was able to use a that for loop to add to the set and then recursevely redo it for the right half.

Comment: Why? just use `list(set(Lst))`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do it multiple ways as part of the exercises i'm doing to learn reccursion

Comment: I mean sure... but this isn't really a useful application of recursion, if you want to learn recursion you're better off implementing _useful_ use cases for it. Like tree traversal or merge sort or something. Trying to shoe horn recursion into something where it doesn't make sense is a sure fire way to just confuse you instead

Comment: Is the input ordered? That will make a big difference to the algorithm (unless you're allowed just to call `sort` first!).

Comment: Of course this only gives you one half of the numbers. You fetch the first half, then the first quarter, then the first eighth, etc. You never look at the numbers in the second half of the original array.

Comment: yes the list would be ordered, i'm just a little stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the work although it's not optimal:

```
def unique(Lst):
        s = set()
        if len(Lst) == 1:
            return {Lst[0]}
    
        mid = len(Lst)//2
        for item in Lst[:mid]:
               if item not in s:
                   s.add(item)
        s |= unique(Lst[mid:])
        return s
```

P.S. if you want uniqueness, you can just do this: `set([1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8])`

EDIT:
your problem was that you forgot to add results from recursive call to the set, which already contains your items (`s`)

Comment: this is very much along the train of thought I had. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

One recursive solution, for example, would be:

```
def unique(Lst):
    if len(Lst) == 1:
        return {Lst[0]} 

    m = len(Lst) // 2
    left_values = unique(Lst[:m])
    right_values = unique(Lst[m:])
    merge_step = set.union(left_values, right_values)
    return merge_step
```

The divide & conquer solution does pretty much this:

- If the subproblem size is 1, return a set containing the only element
- The merge step merges the left and right subproblems using set union. The union of two sets is the set of all unique elements contained in at least one of those sets.